# IONIC 5 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I had this error while trying to get data from an API for my ionic 5 application. I tried removing all the arrays but is not working. Can anybody help?

Here are my files:

**types.ts**

```
export interface Activity {
    area_metadata: Areametadatum[];
    items: Item[];
    api_info: Apiinfo;
}

export interface Apiinfo {
    status: string;
}

export interface Item {
    update_timestamp: string;
    timestamp: string;
    valid_period: Validperiod;
    forecasts: Forecast[];
}

export interface Forecast {
    area: string;
    forecast: string;
}

export interface Validperiod {
    start: string;
    end: string;
}

export interface Areametadatum {
    name: string;
    label_location: Labellocation;
}

export interface Labellocation {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAllActivities(): Observable<Activity> {
    return this._httpClient.get<Activity>(API);
  }
}

const API = "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/2-hour-weather-forecast";
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from "../authentication/authentication-service";
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../types';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  activityList: Observable<Activity>;

  constructor(apiService: ApiService) {
    this.activityList = apiService.getAllActivities();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-card button *ngFor="let activity of activityList">
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{activity.items}}</ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-header>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: `apiService.getAllActivities().subscribe(data => this.activityList = data);`

Comment: hi sorry! where do i include this?

Comment: In your component constructor

Comment: still got the same error

Comment: Do a console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Subscription**

`getAllActivities()` function returns an observable. You need to subscribe to it and assign the local variable within the subscription.

```js
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  activityList = [];        // <-- type should be array not `observable`

  constructor(apiService: ApiService) {
    apiService.getAllActivities().subscribe(    // <-- subscribe here
      response => {
        this.activityList = response;
      },
      error => {
        // always good practice to handle error in HTTP observables
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Option 2: `async` pipe**

Alternatively, you could retain the `activityList` as an `observable` and include the `async` pipe in the template.

But change the observable type to `any`. It will actually be Angular HTTP observable.

Controller

```js
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  activityList: Observable<any>;      // <-- change the type to `any`

  constructor(apiService: ApiService) {
    this.activityList = apiService.getAllActivities();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ion-card button *ngFor="let activity of activityList | async">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>{{activity?.items}}</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: I'm having this error at the line this.activityList. Here is the error: Type 'Activity' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please see if it works for you.